# Trying to create a "generic" Task Scheduler xml to push to multiple machines. Need assistance with the coding please

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

So Im trying to create a "generic" so to speak Windows Task Scheduler xml that I can push to multiple computers and just import it directly into Task Scheduler without having to edit things like username and filepath and all that jazz. Ive got a bat file that is already set up to run via the scheduled task, but I need help figuring out what is the correct coding that I would need to use in order to have the bat files location be automatically entered and saved when the xml file for the task is imported to another computer.
Here is the code for the xml file that I have so far (I did the basic setup using Task Scheduler then exported the task):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2021-09-13T01:19:32.4413372</Date>
    <Author>PC\%User%</Author>
    <Description>This task will backup the main (C:\) drive on this computer every other week on Sunday, Tuesday, and Thursday at 18:36:00 (6:36pm) to the home network storage device (or NAS) that is located near and connected to the wireless router.</Description>
    <URI>\Auto Backup of Main Drive</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2021-09-24T18:36:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Sunday />
          <Tuesday />
          <Thursday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>2</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>%User%</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>true</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
      <Count>18</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"%SystemRoot%\NeverDelete_Backup\MainDriveBackup.bat"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Is %SystemRoot% the correct way to point to the file location for the bat file (it is supposed to be in a folder on the main drive)?

Is PC%User% correct in terms of Author?

Is %User% the correct way to make the current user the one that will be running the task?

Please forgive my noob-ness, This is my first time actually editing the xml file for a task from Task Scheduler. If Im completely wrong or have some things right or whatever the case may be, please help me to correct all the problems.
I just want a simple way to push a scheduled task to multiple machines and not have to change everything each time for each specific machine.

Thanks in advance for any help!
All the best to everyone and stay Healthy, Happy, and Safe!